# can connect to wifi router but not the internet 12.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, 12.10, internet

I believe I have tried every trick in the book!

I am able to access my router from my Ubuntu desktop but not even a single site on the internet.

I have installed the drivers for my PCI Wi-Fi card following the procedure at [How to install a D-Link DWA-525 wireless network card in Ubuntu 10.04](http://steveswinsburg.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/how-to-install-a-d-link-dwa-525-wireless-network-card-in-ubuntu-10-04/).

Earlier it didn't connect to the internet and kept prompting me for the password.

After I installed the driver and it got connected! But now I can't access the internet and can only access my router.

I deleted the `resolv.conf` file.

I have also tried the "rkill" command and it shows it is unlocked.

I have even tried pinging the IPs: `8.8.8.8` & `8.8.4.4` and I get replies from both.

I have also added them on my Wi-Fi configuration setup on Ubuntu desktop.

I am new to Ubuntu but learning fast :-)

These are the things I don't like about Ubuntu, the simple tasks are difficult for a person coming from windows.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to ping `8.8.8.8` you are actually connected to the internet.
You should check your DNS settings. It sounds like hostnames are not resolved correctly.
Check your `resolv.conf` file for the following line:

```
nameserver <IP>
```

Where `<IP>` should be an accessible DNS-server.
You can apply `8.8.8.8` as DS-IP as well.

Comment: +1 for a clear answer.  I had the same issue on 14.04 which I resolved by removing /etc/resolv.conf and putting in a symlink to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf.